# how to parse multiple statements including variable in the text widget

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a `Python` calculator in `tkinter` and am having trouble trying to figure out a way to implement a input area for the user.
I'm trying to create a calculator which would parse `Python` statements as well as calculator like statements. For example, a user may enter multiple lines like:

```
 x = (2*2)+1
 sqrt(x)
```

I've though of using the text widget for input, but then I wouldn't know how to make `Python` parse the strings and obviously this sort of multiple statements including variable assignments are not possible in entry widgets. What alternatives/solutions do I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is too general.

Comment: @jabu.hlong , just how is this general? I'm only asking solution to a specific issue

Comment: You could try finding out or asking (1.)  how parse the strings from whatever using python or(2.) how to do your multiple statements including variable possible

Comment: futhermore 'Implementing a python calculator' sounds like if you put in a little bit more effort in finding a solution you would do just fine.

Comment: @jabu.hlong , okay, I edited the question; thank you :-)

Comment: Are you asking how to do the parsing, or how to create the UI?

Comment: @BryanOakley , I know how to make the overall UI, But I don't know how to parse multiple statements  that the user would input into the text widget, like stated above.